# Kotlin multiplatform. Ktor download big file and save to local file

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

I have the kotlin multiplatform mobile app for Android and iOS targets.

In the app i need to download a big file (50MB), show progress while download, save it locally, verify with MD5, than read line by line and do some action.

As i understand Ktor is best http client for kmm. Also, i found some tips how to show progress.
But in all example i found all contents is downloaded to memory and only after this i can save it to file (shared code can not do this, i need to call expect/actual code separately)
But i want to save a file while downloading, without putting it to the memory. Is it possible?
Or 50MB in memory is not a problem and i can keep it here?